# Convert query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im working on ecommerce platform. I have a query in normal form. i want to convert to codeigniter.

this is my query

```
SELECT products.product_name,products.product_id,products.short_description,pi.img,
CASE WHEN products.sp_price=0 THEN products.price WHEN products.sp_price!=0 THEN products.sp_price END as pprice FROM 
(`offers_products`) JOIN `products` ON `offers_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`product_id`  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_name as img,product_id as pid from product_images GROUP BY pid)pi 
ON `products`.`product_id` = `pi`.`pid` .
```

How do i convert this to codeigniter query.

I tried, but getting syntax error. Please help me, im new to codeigniter.

Comment: If you get an error you should include it.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to codeigniter"?  Do you want to use their query builder (also called active record) class?

Comment: iwant to access ->result(), so i need to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert your query. And also the is no rule that you should use codeigniter query only.

you can use

```
$res = $this->db->query("your query here")->result();
```

`$res` will have that `result()` you want.
This will help you.

For more reference, check [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: I didnt find this in that page.

Comment: iwant to access ->result(), can i do with this

Comment: Yes, you can do that, first try and see, if you get any error, came back.

Comment: yes, this is working. i printed the result from query. thank yo,.. its so simple

Comment: Glad it helped you. if answer was helpful, please consider accepting the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
public function method_name()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT products.product_name,products.product_id,products.short_description,pi.img,    CASE WHEN products.sp_price=0 THEN products.price WHEN products.sp_price!=0 THEN products.sp_price END as pprice FROM     (`offers_products`) JOIN `products` ON `offers_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`product_id`     LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_name as img,product_id as pid from product_images GROUP BY pid)pi     ON `products`.`product_id` = `pi`.`pid`");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; 
}
```

We use `result_array` for pass data as Objective array

Comment: Thanks for your replay. im trying with one more answer, after that i will try this.